# mysql select sum group by date

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

Quick question, I have the following table

```
+-------------+---------------------+
| total       | o_date              |
+-------------+---------------------+
|          35 | 01-11-2009 19:32:44 | 
|        41.5 | 01-12-2009 22:33:49 | 
|        61.5 | 01-23-2009 22:08:24 | 
|          66 | 02-01-2009 22:33:57 | 
|       22.22 | 02-01-2009 22:37:34 | 
|       29.84 | 04-20-2009 15:23:49 | 
+-------------+---------------------+
```

I would like to add up the total for each month and group the total by month. So for instance **Jan-> 138 Feb-> 88.2 Apr-> 29.84**

Any clues about it. Thanks

Answer (score 96, accepted):

This solution will give you the month name as a column of your resultset, followed by the total as required.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(o_date), SUM(total) 
FROM theTable
GROUP BY YEAR(o_date), MONTH(o_date)
```

Comment: You may also want to add the year to the select list -> YEAR(o_date)

Comment: Or, to get it in the format you specified, you can do SELECT CONCAT(MONTHNAME(o_date), '-> ', SUM(total))

Comment: Very usefull! and u can add columns to group by

Answer (score 12):

```
select year(o_date), month(o_date), sum(total)
from table
group by year(o_date), month(o_date);
```

Comment: That's assuming you want months in different years grouped seperately

Answer (score 7):

Get Month And Year wise data from MySQL database:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(o_date), YEAR(o_date), SUM(total) 
FROM the_table 
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(total)
FROM table
GROUP BY MONTH(o_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT year(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) year, month(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) month, sum(amount) total
FROM {my_table}
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY year, month;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Group BY`, like this:

```
select count(A_id) As Tid,Day(CrDate) from Ap Group By Day(CrDate)
```