# sum up amount of entries in a table in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've got a table that looks like this

[image]

I want to display the amount of entries by a certain agent. I know I can use e.g.

```
orders.sum(:demand)
```

to sum up the demand. (table is called orders) However, there has to be a way to sum up the entries right? E.g. for agent 1, this would be 4, for agent 2 it would be 1 and for agent 3 it would be 4 entries (as can be seen in the screenshot).

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select, group and sum results from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556289/select-group-and-sum-results-from-database)

Comment: You need to use sql's `group by` clause. How to use this in rails is described in the duplicate topic I linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you need is the amount of entries by `:agent_id`, this should work:

```
Order.group(:agent_id).count
```

And the result is

> => {1=>4, 2=>2, 3=>3}

#### Edit:

If what you need is the count of the ***current_user***:

```
Order.where(agent_id: @current_user).count
```

So if ***current_user*** is '1', you get:

> => 4

Comment: this actually works as you described. I only want to display the "count" of the current user. Each user can either be an agent or a client. So user_id is not necessarily = agent_id. Anyway, each agent shall only see his own count..

Comment: So what you need is, to find the number of entries by the currect user? If so, where do you have your currect user?

Comment: do you mean my sessions_helper? 
`def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end`

Comment: Strange as it is, this returns "0" for any agent that i tried.

Comment: updated the original table, maybe this is because of the actual entries in the "order" column??

Comment: That must be because your `@current_user` variable stores a user without entries, can you check the value of that varaible just before the call of you `.count`?

Comment: `CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "4"]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "orders" WHERE "oreders"."agent_id" IS NULL`

Comment: Ok, lets try this, do you have your `.count` method call in a controller??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138752/discussion-between-alejandro-montilla-and-krawalla).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by 'certain', you're sending some sort of request to the controller, specifying the agent you want to query...

```
Order.where(agent_id: params[:agent_id]).count
```

Comment: well this sounds pretty reasonable... however, this error occurs:
`undefined local variable or method 'params' for #<User:0x007ff180140f18>`

Comment: This is psudo code, you'll need to pass in the agent_id somehow, this could either be via the request parameters (params) from the controller, or from a variable derived by some other means:

agent = 123
Order.where(agent_id: agent).count

Answer (score 1):

With activerecord you can use the `count` method for counting the results.

```
Order.count # => 9
```

With the `group` method you can group the results by another column.

```
Order.group(:agent_id) # => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [ ... ] >
```

Together you can get the results you want:

```
Order.group(:agent_id).count # => {1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

Comment: this actually works as you described. I only want to display the "count" of the current user. Each user can either be an agent or a client. So user_id is not necessarily = agent_id. Anyway, each agent shall only see his own count...