# MySQL, how to do a sum by product and by month

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below

```
 Date        |  Product      |  Qty
-------------|---------------|------
12-Dec-12    | reference1    | 1
14-Dec-12    | reference2    | 2
14-Dec-12    | reference1    | 3
1-Jan-13     | reference2    | 4
3-Jan-13     | reference2    | 5
3-Jan-13     | reference3    | 6
```

and I would like to get it as below through a query

```
Product    | Dec 2012   | Jan 2013
===========|============|========== 
reference1 |    4       | 0
reference2 |    2       | 9
reference3 |    0       | 6
```

I know how to group already, my problem is how to have dynamic column (I would like to be able to choose last `6 months`, `12 months` or `24 months`).

Comment: Related: [mysql select sum group by date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/937652/2943403)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to *pivot* the data from rows into columns.  MySQL does not have a pivot function but you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` to get the result:

```
select product,
  sum(case when month(date) = 12 and year(date) = 2012 
           then qty else 0 end) Dec2012,
  sum(case when month(date) = 1 and year(date) = 2013 
           then qty else 0 end) Jan2013
from yourtable
group by product
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79edf/2).

This can also be written using a subquery to get the date in the format of Month-year:

```
select product,
  sum(case when MonthYear = 'Dec_2012' then qty else 0 end) Dec2012,
  sum(case when MonthYear = 'Jan_2013' then qty else 0 end) Jan2013
from
(
  select product,
    date_format(date, '%b_%Y') MonthYear,
    qty
  from yourtable
) src
group by product;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79edf/12).

Then if you wanted to generate a list of dates dynamically or will have an unknown number of dates that you want to return, you can use a prepared statement to generate dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when MonthYear = ''',
      MonthYear,
      ''' then qty else 0 end) AS ',
      MonthYear
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM 
(
  select product,
    date_format(date, '%b_%Y') MonthYear,
    qty
  from yourtable
) src;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT product, ', @sql, ' 
                   from
                   (
                    select product,
                      date_format(date, ''%b_%Y'') MonthYear,
                      qty
                    from yourtable
                   ) src
                   GROUP BY product');


PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/79edf/11). All three will give you the result:

```
|    PRODUCT | DEC_2012 | JAN_2013 |
------------------------------------
| reference1 |        4 |        0 |
| reference2 |        2 |        9 |
| reference3 |        0 |        6 |
```

Comment: waouh, 4 minutes to edit my post, and give me the answer, that's a real performance. thanks, you found out my issue, I did not know where to look. I guess with your answer I can manage.

Comment: @VincentAndre I edited my answer to include a dynamic version.