# REALM - Sum and Group Result By date

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, orm, realm

I'm using Realm as an alternate to SQLite, this library is awesome. i'm wondering if i can do something like [mysql select sum group by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937652/mysql-select-sum-group-by-date) using Realm. if so, how do I approach it?

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1220

Comment: that's also mine actually, haha