# mysql query to add data with column the same

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table where i may put multiple entries for the same date.

Does anyone know a query which will go through the data and add values up if they land on the same date?

for e.g. 2015-10-01 will have one line with Value1 having the answer of 3

```
id  date         Value1  Value2  Value3
1   2015-10-01   1       1       1     
2   2015-10-01   2       2       2       
3   2015-10-02   1       1       1       
4   2015-10-02   2       2       2       
5   2015-10-03   1       1       1       
6   2015-10-03   2       2       2       
7   2015-10-03   3       3       3
```

Comment: can you explain bit more?

Comment: Ever heard about `select`?

Comment: see here a similar question where a sum is done on values based on date http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937652/mysql-select-sum-group-by-date

Comment: feel abit dumb now. used the sum function and working right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need group by and sum():

select date, sum(value1) as total from table group by date

Comment: Thank you. tried googling it but seems i didnt try hard enough