# MySQL sum amount by each months from last 12 month to this month

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sum amount of each month from last 12 months ago until now.
So how to write the MySQL query, I'm so poor with MySQL.

```
select sum(amount) as monthly_expense from tb_expense 
where between last 12 and now();
```

Comment: Please, read [how to ask useful questions aka MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [mysql select sum group by date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/937652/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned your table format and which field stores date on your table. But for your functionality you need to have a column which stores date for each record. Assuming you have a column `expense_date` try this :

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS monthly_expense FROM tb_expense 
WHERE tb_expense.date > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH))
```

Let us know if your table data is different.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want:

```
select sum(amount) as monthly_expense
from tb_expense
where datecol >= curdate() - interval 1 year;
```

`datecol` is whatever column stores the relevant date in the table.

If you want this per month, then use `group by`:

```
select year(datecol), month(datecol), sum(amount) as monthly_expense
from tb_expense
where datecol >= curdate() - interval 1 year
group by year(datecol), month(datecol);
```

Note that in this formulation, the first and last months will be partial.  That is what your question specifically asks for.