# Fetching sum of amount for a specific year from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have the following table with dummy values in mysql database:

```
id cnic amount depositDate receivedBy receivingZone remarks
1  11111 10000 01-Nov-2019 11111      1              Ok
2  11111 10000 07-Nov-2019 11111      1              ok
```

Now i want to get the sum of amount from the table for specific year (2019 in this case) where the year came from current timestamp (it may be 2020, 2021 etc depends on the current date)

Any help plz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql select sum group by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937652/mysql-select-sum-group-by-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function to get the year of the `depositDate` column and also the current year and then sum only the values which match:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount
FROM yourtable
WHERE YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(depositDate, '%d-%b-%Y')) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Comment: now how will i get the amount value means i cant get it in $amount variable

Comment: @SKYz see my edit. This will make the sum available in the `amount` field of the row's data.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: amount in C:\xampp\htdocs\skyz\RWF\user\pages\mcInfo.php on line 57

Comment: @SKYz that should work if you're using the current query from my answer (where I added the column alias)

Comment: @SKYz good to hear. you can make that change (adding `AS amount`) to any of the answers you've given.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select sum(amount)
from tablename
where year(depositdate)=year(now())
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample year, we need to recognize first the `date` using `str_to_date`

```
select sum(amount)
from tableA
where year(now()) =  year(str_to_date(depositdate, '%d-%b-%Y'))
```

Comment: @Nick, thanks, but it will still extract the year even using %M, anyways I updated my answer. https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=gNbQw95iUR

Comment: Interesting. Normally `STR_TO_DATE` is so fussy it will fall over on the slightest mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

I would write the `WHERE` clause to be sargable:

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM yourTable
WHERE depositDate >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-01-01') AND
      depositDate < DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) ,'%Y-01-01');
```

This approach, while a bit more verbose than the other answers which use the `YEAR()` function, would allow an index on the `depositDate` column to be used.

Comment: now how will i get the amount value means i cant get it in $amount variable after sql fetch it