# SQL Query to select Specific Month in MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count

I have a database where I have date field 2020-08-03

I am trying to get the data for each month

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM new_caseWHERE sla_client = 'ITA' AND MONTH(sysdate) = MONTH(current_date ()) 
AND YEAR(sysdate) = YEAR(current_date())
```

The above works for the current month and year what would I use to query in the above for January 2020, February 2020 and so on

Comment: Not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937652/mysql-select-sum-group-by-date is similar.

Comment: I am trying to echo just one month at a time, January's count = 20 from one Query as there is different queries with different months and functions

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want aggregation:

```
select
    date_format(mydate, '%Y-%m') yyyy_mm,
    count(*) cnt
from new_case
where sla_client = 'ITA'
group by date_format(mydate, '%Y-%m')
order by yyyy_mm
```

This gives you one row per month, with the count of rows in that month (if there is no data for a given month, then it just does not appear in the resultset).

If you need to filter on a given date range, then I would recommend using a `where` clause that filters directly on the date values rather than applying date functions. Say you want the last 3 months and the current month, then:

```
select
    date_format(mydate, '%Y-%m') yyyy_mm,
    count(*) cnt
from new_case
where 
    sla_client = 'ITA'
    and mydate >= date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') - interval 3 month
    and mydate < date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') + interval 1 month
group by date_format(mydate, '%Y-%m')
order by yyyy_mm
```