# How to select from mysql that group by month in one year and sum value in a month?

Tags: mysql

```
received_amount | updated_at
----------------------------
4000            | 2020-11-02
2000            | 2020-11-03
1000            | 2020-12-02
1000            | 2020-12-04
3000            | 2021-01-02
2000            | 2020-01-02
```

This is my database table named "*payment*" structured and data on it.

Now I want to display something like below mentioned table data in my php web page when user select the year from calendar (I've use Zebra date picker for this). Zebra date picker gives the year.

In this scenario user select the year 2020 and it's should show the values as below.

```
Year  | Month   | Monthly Total
----------------------------
2020  | November| 6000
2020  | December| 2000
```

Comment: What about January 2020? I can see it there in the data.

Comment: If the user selects the year then why do you have in your expected results rows of more than 1 year?

Comment: @TheImpaler Ahha. Missed it. Thanks

Comment: @forpas Only the selected year should shown. Thank you.

Comment: Related: [mysql select sum group by date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/937652/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select year, month, monthly_total
from (
  select
    extract(year from updated_at) as year,
    extract(month from updated_at) as m,
    monthname(updated_at) as month,
    sum(receive_amount) as monthly_total
  from t
  where extract(year from updated_at) = 2020
  group by year, month, m
) x
order by year, m
```

Result:

```
 year  month     monthly_total 
 ----- --------- ------------- 
 2020  January   2000          
 2020  November  6000          
 2020  December  2000
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/soRrX4z5D9aHawEBWCqhcW/1).

Comment: Hi. The query is working as expected in my database table. But how can I get the result into a table in my php page? I have tried but gives errors. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use group by like this in your query

```
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM updated_at), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM updated_at)
```

and then select like this

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM updated_at) as Year,
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM updated_at) as Month,
       SUM(received_amount) as Monthly_Total
```

Comment: Your code also helped me. Thank you very much.